# F# Types and Looping

Tags: loops, types, f#

I am working on an F# tutorial that creates a deck of cards.  The types are listed, but I cannot understand how to loop through the types to create the map of the full deck.  I expected to do something like

```
Foreach rank in ranks
   Foreach suit in suits
       somehow combine the two
   next suit
next rank
```

Is there no way to do this?  Below are the types created.

I think if I changed them from types to lists they could union, right?  So, what's the point of types?

```
type suits=
    |Spade=1
    |Heart=2
    |Club=3
    |Diamond=4

type ranks=
    |ValCard of int
    |Jack 
    |Queen
    |King

type deck= Deck of ranks * suits
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233216.aspx) is a good choice for representing cards. You have comparison among suits and among ranks for free, and easily convert enums from/to `int`.

```
type suit =
    | Spade = 1
    | Heart = 2
    | Club = 3
    | Diamond = 4

type rank = 
    | Ace = 1 | Two = 2 | Three = 3 | Four = 4 | Five = 5 | Six = 6 | Seven = 7 
    | Eight = 8 | Nine = 9 | Ten = 10 | Jack = 11 | Queen = 12 | King = 13

/// 'Card' is a type which represents a particular card     
type Card = Card of rank * suit

/// 'deck' is a list consisting of all cards in a full deck
let deck = [ for r in 1..13 do
               for s in 1..4 do
                 yield Card(enum<rank> r, enum<suit> s) ]
```

If you go for [discriminated unions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx), you have to manually make lists of all `suit`s and all `rank`s. The advantage is better pattern matching of DUs than that of enums.

```
type suit =
    | Spade
    | Heart
    | Club
    | Diamond

type rank = | Ace | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven 
            | Eight | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King

type Card = Card of rank * suit

let private suits = [Spade; Heart; Club; Diamond]
let private ranks = [Ace; Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven; 
                     Eight; Nine; Ten; Jack; Queen; King]

let deck = [ for rank in ranks do
               for suit in suits do
                 yield Card(rank, suit) ]
```

Comment: DUs also provide comparison "for free" (based on case order).

Comment: I don't think that enum is a good choice. You even can change the loop values to "-10..20" and "0..6" and your code still creates some invalid "cards". And as noted, you also have comparision on DU for free like enums.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative approach which uses a discriminated union which meshes more nicely than enums with F#'s syntax

```
type suit=
    |Spade
    |Heart
    |Club
    |Diamond
    static member all = [Spade;Heart;Club;Diamond]

type rank=
    |ValCard of int
    |Jack 
    |Queen
    |King
    static member all =([1..10]|> List.map (ValCard)) @ [Jack;Queen;King]

type card = |Card of rank * suit

let all_cards = suit.All |> List.collect (fun s -> rank.all |> List.map (fun r -> Card(r,s))
```

Then you can do some neat pattern matching like

```
all_cards 
|> List.iter (fun c ->
    match c with
    |Card(King,Spade) -> ...
    |Card(King,_) -> ...
    |Card(_) -> ...
```

You could even define some Active patterns to get red/black cards .

Comment: You forgot `Valcard(10)`; it's the drawback with manually listing all values.

Comment: Note that `ValCard of int` is a leaking abstraction since `ValCard 0` and `ValCard 11`, etc are illegal values.

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to pad's answer, you could also use reflection to generate the deck:

```
type Union<'T> private () =
  static member val Cases = 
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'T>)
    |> Array.map (fun case -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, null) :?> 'T)

let deck = 
  [ for rank in Union<rank>.Cases do
      for suit in Union<suit>.Cases do
        yield Card(rank, suit) ]
```