# Discriminated Union initialization

Tags: f#

Is there a simpler way to initialize this deck of cards using F#?

```
let create() = [ 0..12 ]

type Suit = 
    | Spades of list<int>
    | Hearts of list<int>
    | Clubs of list<int>
    | Diamonds of list<int>

let spades = create() |> Spades
let hearts = create() |> Hearts
let clubs = create() |> Clubs
let diamonds = create() |> Diamonds
```

Specifically, I would like to simplify the initialization of these four suits.
Is there a simpler way to do this?

Could I enumerate the types of on this discriminated union and assign it to some "deck" structure?

NOTE:

I am new to F#. So please forgive me if this question seems ignorant.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29001670/126014

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# Types and Looping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834396/f-types-and-looping)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that there's a more succinct way, but I also wouldn't model playing cards like this, because it doesn't help **making illegal states unrepresentable**. As an example, I can do this:

```
> Spades [-1; 10; 100];;
val it : Suit = Spades [-1; 10; 100]
```

What does that even mean?

---

## Alternative model

Instead, I'd probably model cards like this:

```
type Suit = Diamonds | Hearts | Clubs | Spades
type Face =
    | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
    | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = { Suit: Suit; Face: Face }
```

This would enable you to express any *valid* card:

```
> { Suit = Spades; Face = Ace };;
val it : Card = {Suit = Spades;
                 Face = Ace;}
```

On the other hand, you can't express `invalid` cards:

```
> { Suit = Spades; Face = Hundred };;

  { Suit = Spades; Face = Hundred };;
  ------------------------^^^^^^^

stdin(4,25): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'Hundred' is not defined
```

Initialisation looks, in this model, a bit cumbersome, but on the other hand, the following `deck` is an immutable *value*, so once it's defined, you can reuse the deck again and again.

```
let deck = [
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Two   };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Three };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Four  };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Five  };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Six   };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Seven };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Eight };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Nine  };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Ten   };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Jack  };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Queen };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = King  };
    { Suit = Diamonds; Face = Ace   };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Two   };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Three };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Four  };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Five  };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Six   };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Seven };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Eight };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Nine  };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Ten   };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Jack  };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Queen };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = King  };
    { Suit = Hearts;   Face = Ace   };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Two   };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Three };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Four  };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Five  };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Six   };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Seven };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Eight };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Nine  };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Ten   };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Jack  };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Queen };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = King  };
    { Suit = Clubs;    Face = Ace   };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Two   };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Three };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Four  };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Five  };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Six   };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Seven };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Eight };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Nine  };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Ten   };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Jack  };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Queen };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = King  };
    { Suit = Spades;   Face = Ace   }; ]
```

Although this looks tedious, you only have to write this once. Since `deck` is a value, you can make it a value that belongs to a module. Clients can simply use this value, instead of having to initialise a deck by themselves.

Comment: You can simplify the deck creation with 
`let deck = [
    for suit in [Diamonds;Hearts;Clubs;Spades] do
    for face in [Two;Three;Four;Five;Six;Seven;Eight;Nine;Ten;Jack;Queen;King;Ace] do
        yield { Suit=suit; Face=face }
]`