# How would I perform property-based testing on a card game's Deal function?

Tags: unit-testing, f#, fscheck, property-based-testing, property-testing

I am studying property-based testing and am curious how I would apply this type of testing to a BlackJack game's Deal function.

Here's a unit test (aka: Example-based test):

```
[<Test>]
let ``deal two cards`` () =
    let hand = 2
    let dealPlayer cardCount = 
        [for i in [1..cardCount] -> shuffleDeck.Pop] 
        |> Seq.toList

    (dealPlayer hand).Length |> should equal (2)
```

What would be an example of a property-based test?

- Would I test that the two cards are within a range of 4 suits? 
  (i.e. Spades, Diamonds, Hearts, Clubs)
  Wouldn't relying on a static type already ensure that for me?
- Would I test that the two cards are within the range of numbers or faces?
  (i.e. 2..10;Jack;Queen;King;Ace)
  Again, wouldn't relying on a static type already ensure that for me?

Again, what should I consider when performing property-based tests for a blackjack game?

Comment: you already have an property (although a trivial one): "if I deal two cards then the player should have two cards"

Comment: some will probably look for edge cases like "if dealt x cards then busted" (don't know the exact Blackjack rules either but assuming the 2 is in there then surely if you have 11 cards or more you are at 22+ so you lost)

Comment: Or if I'm dealt (n) cards, then dealer's deck is (n) cards less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you model the domain (in this case: a card game) using [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), the type system takes care of many things for you.

There are already examples of modelling a card game [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29001670/126014) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33858023/126014), but in essence, you can model it like this:

```
type Suit = Diamonds | Hearts | Clubs | Spades
type Face =
    | Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten
    | Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = { Suit: Suit; Face: Face }
```

This **makes illegal states unrepresentable**, which means that it doesn't even make sense to test whether a `Suit` is one of `Diamonds`, `Hearts`, `Clubs`, or `Spades`; these are the only values it can have.

> what should I consider when performing property-based tests for a blackjack game?

I don't know, that's for you to figure out (I also don't know the rules for Blackjack), but here's an [example of property based testing applied to the tennis rules](https://vimeo.com/144800642).

Sports and games tend to be easy targets for Property Based Testing, because the rules of the game map to properties.

In general, properties are **invariants** of the domain. *Given* that certain preconditions are fulfilled, *when* you exercise the [SUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test), *then* certain postconditions should hold.

You may also consider watching my [Introduction to Property-based Testing with F#](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/fsharp-property-based-testing-introduction) Pluralsight course.